# Best way to handle this question/answer

Tags: discussion, moderators

This question was posted recently: [What are some techniques you can use for older table saws that lack riving knives?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/9564/what-are-some-techniques-you-can-use-for-older-table-saws-that-lack-riving-knive)

It has problems on two levels.  First it posts an answer along with the question. Second it is very similar to another question.  As a new moderator I have been asked to convert the answer portion of the question to an answer, which do not believe is possible while giving credit to the new user.  He has clearly spent some time and energy preparing this submission and I do not want to discourage a new user and have the question closed.

I am open to suggestions from the WSE community.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct, the original contributor has to edit the question and post the answer content as a standalone answer. It is ok to close questions as duplicates as long as we are friendly about it and help new contributors learn how to use the site better.